# Does React's Context handle browser back button?

Tags: reactjs, state, react-context, browser-state

In my application I have a context for search information. I can do new searches, clear the searches, etc -- and everything works okay.

The issue is, when I click the browser's back button, my context doesn't update with the old data.

Previously I used `history.push` and pushed a state object, which I picked up in all my components. After having switched all of that to use a context, I'm having trouble.

---

The code is set up a bit like this:

- An overarching component SiteLayoutProvider

A definition for my state:

- `const [searchData, setSearchData] = useState(null)`

and a return statement containing the following:

```
<SearchContext.Provider value={[searchData, setSearchData]}
   ...
</SearchContext.Provider>
```

Now I can consume this and pull this context in everywhere I need it with `useContext`. I can perform a search which will `setSearchData`, and any console.logs in child components are accurate -- I can clear the search and perform new searches, and the information is still logged accurately. But when I click the back button, what's in the context, and what's logged, doesn't represent the previous data.

Am I completely misunderstanding the capabilities of "vanilla" context? Do I *need* to use `history.push`? What is the "right" way to do this?

Comment: when you say does context handle the browser back button, it does not... context only allows you to pass state globally throughout your react application

Comment: @RobertTerrell I suppose there's nothing "wrong" with history.push, it's just that I'd rather not use it if there's a way to manage it with context. It seems everywhere I look that this _is_ the way to go because of what you've said. I _was_ under the impression my understanding was incorrect, but thank you for reiterating. I will submit to react router